# Executing C program in PHP using exec() in fedora14

Tags: php

I want to run simple C program that prints hello in php using exec() from browser.

```
exec("/home/xyz/hello",$out);
```

I am not getting any output in browser and even in command line also.

I am using fedora14 and I have disabled SELinux still then I am not getting output, its just displaying blank page in browser.

Comment: Either output `$output` in a loop or imploded or try `passthru()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your code, use this:

```
echo shell_exec("/home/xyz/hello");
```

Comment: nice! I'm happy it helped you, sign my answer because this way I can get more privileges here to help more people